# Does g++ support scalar_storage_order?

Tags: c++, g++

Does g++ support `sclar_storage_order`?

I've tested it in g++6 and g++7, but it only warns and does not handle it properly.

**Source Code:**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#else
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#endif

typedef struct {
    uint32_t a;
    uint16_t b;
} __attribute__((scalar_storage_order("big-endian"))) SS;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uint8_t raw[] = { 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0x11, 0x22 };
    SS* instance = (SS*)raw;
    printf("%x, %x\n", instance->a, instance->b);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
gcc-6 source.c && ./a.out
aabbccdd, 1122

g++-6 source.cpp && ./a.out
source.cpp:16:53: warning: ‘scalar_storage_order’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
 } __attribute__((scalar_storage_order("big-endian"))) SS;
                                                     ^
ddccbbaa, 2211
```

Comment: "Warns" about what? Please show us the warnings.

Comment: There's a pretty cool web site out there called www.google.com. All I had to do was type "scalar_storage_order gcc". and it immediately returned a link to the answer to this question: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Layout-Pragmas.html

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude updated my question

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: You probably wanted https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html. This isn't about the `#pragma`

Comment: Have you tried placing the `__attribute__` specifier in the "preferred" location, after the `struct` keyword?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: the `visibility` attribute specifically notes that it is the only attribute that **must** occur there.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, I've tried that. but It doesn't work too.

Comment: [The GCC test](https://gitlab.indel.ch/thirdparty/gcc/blob/14964a3615b5f0145e6dceba6aee6d3e8b138f71/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/sso-4.c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [patch for the C++ front end was posted](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-10/msg00527.html), but it was reverted on the branch before the merge:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r229934 | ebotcazou | 2015-11-07 19:10:36 +0100 (Sat, 07 Nov 2015) | 8 lines

c-family/
        * c-common.c (handle_scalar_storage_order_attribute): Accept attribute
        in place in C but not in C++.
testsuite/
        * c-c++-common/sso-[1-7].c: Move to...
        * gcc.dg/sso-[2-8].c: ...here.
        * g++.dg/sso-[2-8].C: ... and here.
```

The merged patch registers the `#pragma scalar_storage_order` handler for both C and C++, but the C++ front end was not changed to process the internal `global_sso` flag controlled by the pragma, so there is currently no support whatsoever for this feature in g++.